# Guzzle and Stack Exchange API, parsing error "JSON_ERROR_UTF8"

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to consume the Stack Exchange API with [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I am facing an issue where I can't get the JSON response back: it apparently fails when parsing it.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$parameters = ['pagesize'=>'2','order'=>'desc','sort'=> 'activity','q'=>'laravel eloquent','site'=>'stackoverflow'];
$response = $client->get('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced',['query' => $parameters ]);
```

The resultant effective URL that Guzzle creates [is correct](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?pagesize=2&order=desc&sort=activity&q=laravel%20eloquent&site=stackoverflow): if you open the link in your browser you'll see that it works fine and returns the requested data.

However, Guzzle fails with this error when trying to access the JSON with `$response->json()`:

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ParseException
> Unable to parse JSON data: JSON_ERROR_UTF8 - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

After reading the [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression) again, I believe that the request is compressed and I am not passing the appropriate content header. If this is so, can you please let me know which header I should be passing to get the correct response?

Comment: I am currently using PHP 5.5.3 version

Comment: What if you take wireshark and see the exact request and response?

Comment: Tried downloading and installing wireshark for mac os but it is not responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the following code works for me.

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $parameters = ['pagesize'=>'2','order'=>'desc','sort'=> 'activity','q'=>'laravel eloquent','site'=>'stackoverflow'];
    $params = http_build_query($parameters);
    $request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?'.$params);
    $request->addHeader('Accept-Encoding','GZIP');
    $request->addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    $response = $client->send($request);
    var_dump($response->json());
```